# Equivalent of gpg --sign in golang?

Tags: go, gnupg, pgp, openpgp

I currently have a Perl script that performs a PGP sign on an email address to produce an obfuscated token. The Perl script uses the command line utility GPG version 2.2.8 (on MacOS). I would like to convert this functionality to Go.

The relevant line in Perl:

```
my $token = `printf $emailaddress | gpg --sign -u myprivatekeyname | base64`;
```

My attempt in Go:

```
import (
    "golang.org/x/crypto/openpgp"
    "log"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "bytes"
    )


const privateKey = `-----BEGIN PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----
<the same private key as is used by the GPG tool>
-----END PGP PRIVATE KEY BLOCK-----`

func main() {
    email := "bob@foo.com"
    token := makeToken(email)
    fmt.Println(token)
}

func getPrivateKey() *openpgp.Entity {
    pp := "mypassphrase"
    ppb := []byte(pp)

    entitylist, err := openpgp.ReadArmoredKeyRing(strings.NewReader(privateKey))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    entity := entitylist[0]

    if entity.PrivateKey != nil && entity.PrivateKey.Encrypted {
        err := entity.PrivateKey.Decrypt(ppb)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println("Failed to decrypt key")
        }
    }

    for _, subkey := range entity.Subkeys {
        if subkey.PrivateKey != nil && subkey.PrivateKey.Encrypted {
            err := subkey.PrivateKey.Decrypt(ppb)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("Failed to decrypt subkey")
            }
        }
    }
    return entity
}

func makeToken(email string) string {
    pk := getPrivateKey()
    out := new(bytes.Buffer)
    in, err := openpgp.Sign(out, pk, nil, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    in.Write([]byte(email))
    in.Close()
    return base64.StdEncoding.EncodeToString(out.Bytes())
}
```

Unfortunately the results for a given email addresss (like 'bob@foo.com') are not identical.

I am using the same private key: I exported it from GPG and pasted it into my go code (obviously this is just for testing, I won't leave it like that).

Any idea what Iam doing wrong?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the results _should not_ be identical, as there's an element of randomness in every signature.

Comment: And there are timestamps included.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare signatures based on a binary diff; they [include timestamps](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-5.9). Furthermore, you might apply different compression and signature algorithms. Compare the output of `gpg --list-packets` or `pgpdump` instead.

Looking at a rather arbitrary signature:

```
$ echo foo | gpg --sign | gpg --list-packets
```

Here, you might be using different compression algorithms (or none at all, here: 1):

```
# off=0 ctb=a3 tag=8 hlen=1 plen=0 indeterminate
:compressed packet: algo=1
```

The signature packet might use different digest algorithms (here: `10`):

```
# off=2 ctb=90 tag=4 hlen=2 plen=13
:onepass_sig packet: keyid 8E78E44DFB1B55E9
    version 3, sigclass 0x00, digest 10, pubkey 1, last=1
```

Here we have a timestamp:

```
# off=17 ctb=cb tag=11 hlen=2 plen=10 new-ctb
:literal data packet:
    mode b (62), created 1536744536, name="",
    raw data: 4 bytes
```

And another timestamp (the signing algorithm should be the same for the same key):

```
# off=29 ctb=89 tag=2 hlen=3 plen=563
:signature packet: algo 1, keyid 8E78E44DFB1B55E9
    version 4, created 1536744536, md5len 0, sigclass 0x00
    digest algo 10, begin of digest f4 03
    hashed subpkt 33 len 21 (issuer fpr v4 292F04A99AA52EC6F3088C608E78E44DFB1B55E9)
    hashed subpkt 2 len 4 (sig created 2018-09-12)
    subpkt 16 len 8 (issuer key ID 8E78E44DFB1B55E9)
    data: [4096 bits]
```

By diffing the output of `gpg --list-packets`, you should be able to understand whether there is any noteworthy difference in the output. If you're using the same algorithms and fake the time, you should be able to get the same output.

The constants/magic numbers mentioned above are also defined in [RFC 4880, OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-9).

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I didn't realize that.

Comment: One question: Is the original text recoverable from the output of gpg --sign?

Comment: Please don't ask unrelated follow-up questions in comments. Also be aware this definitely leaves the scope of Stack Overflow, consider asking on Security Stack Exchange or Super User instead.